# Eclipse Kepler does not recognize HTML5 "contenteditable"

Tags: eclipse, html, eclipse-kepler

I am using Eclipse Kepler and when annotating a div with contenteditable tag, it underlines and says "Undefined attribute name". I wonder if this is not yet supported by the HTML editor.

[image]

Comment: Which Kepler version?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use HTML DOCTYPE Declaration for HTML5 in your jsp/html file: "!DOCTYPE html" surround with < and >